# How to configure the guest vm(Ubuntu16.04) to get ip from bridge network of the host vm(Ubuntu16.04) using KVM hypervisor?

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virtual-console

I'm having trouble to get IP from the bridge network which was custom configures for 10.* addresses and now my guest VM was picking default address 192.*.

Comment: You don't configure the guest. The guest can only use the network that the hypervisor provides. Change the networking setting in the hypervisor application.

Answer (score 0):

I used netplan to get bridge ip here is the configuration file to netplan

sudo vim /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

`network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: true
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces:
        - enp9s0`